# Converting Jscript into C# to create Add-in for Sparx EA

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect, jscript

I wrote my code in Jscript for scanning diagrams in the EA Project Browser then create a list of elements regarding the existing elements. The code works without any problem. Currently, I have a problem when I try to convert my code (Jscript) into C# to create a customized Add-in for Enterprise Architect.

This is a part of my code in Jscript:

```
var theModel as EA.Package;
theModel = Repository.Models.GetAt( 0 );
// Iterate through all views (top level packages) in the model
var viewEnumerator = new Enumerator( theModel.Packages );
while ( !viewEnumerator.atEnd() )
{
    var currentView as EA.Package;
    currentView = viewEnumerator.item();

    // Add the name of this view to the output window
    Session.Output( currentView.Name );

    // Iterate through all diagrams in this view

    viewEnumerator.moveNext();
}
```

This is the converted code in c#:

```
EA.Package theModel;
theModel = Repository.Models.GetAt( 0 );

// Iterate through all views (top level packages) in the model
var viewEnumerator = new Enumerator( theModel.Packages );

while ( !viewEnumerator.atEnd() )
{
     EA.Package currentView;
    currentView = viewEnumerator.item();

    // Add the name of this view to the output window
    MessageBox.Show( currentView.Name );

    // Iterate through all diagrams in this view

    viewEnumerator.moveNext();
}
```

However,  I have a problem with the following:

```
 var viewEnumerator = new Enumerator( theModel.Packages );
```

The error is:

> The type or namespace name 'Enumerator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Actually, I have no idea how I can create something similar to this in C#

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop instead of an `Enumerator`

```
EA.Package theModel;
theModel = Repository.Models.GetAt( 0 );

// Iterate through all views (top level packages) in the model
foreach( EA.Package currentView in theModel.Packages )
{
    // Add the name of this view to the output window
    MessageBox.Show( currentView.Name );
}
```

Make sure you type the currentView (and don't use `var`) as the EA.Collection is not strong typed.